# Segmentation fault in array storing in IPC linux

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, ipc, shared-memory

I am trying to store a array in shared from a process and tring to access the same from another process.

Below is the code I am using to store the array

```
#include <iostream> 
    #include <sys/ipc.h> 
    #include <sys/shm.h> 
    #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <stdlib.h>

    using namespace std; 
    int count;
    int main() 
    {

      while(1)
    {
     int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}; 
     int *str1;

     int key=5678;
     // shmget returns an identifier in shmid 
     int shmid = shmget(key,1024, 0666|IPC_CREAT); 
     printf("\nShared Memory Id = %d\n",shmid);

     // shmat to attach to shared memory 
     str1 = (int*) shmat(shmid,(void*)0,0);
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
         *str1=arr[i];
          printf("Data written in memory: %d\n",*str1);
          str1++;
        }
    }
    shmdt((void*)str);
    return 0; 
    }
```

When I am running the program,  it is running upto some extend and giving error as segmentation fault (core dumped) and getting exit from the application.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks and regards,
Prabhakar M

Comment: I suggest some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Pay close attention to where `str1` points to after the loop...

Comment: And ***always*** check for errors!

Comment: Also, if you want people to read your code, format it consistently. Further, extract a [mcve]. Odd are that you'll stumble across the bug yourself doing that.

Comment: I have tried all the way I am not getting it. Please help to sorted it out.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: The code you show won't even build, much less run and crash.

Comment: And a hint: `str1++` modifies the pointer. After it you no longer have the original pointer.

Answer (score -1):

str1++ is the culprit.
Below code is working.

```
    #include <iostream> 
    #include <sys/ipc.h> 
    #include <sys/shm.h> 
    #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <stdlib.h>

    using namespace std; 
    int count;
    int main() 
    {
 int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}; 
     int *str1;

     int key=5678;
     // shmget returns an identifier in shmid 
     int shmid = shmget(key,1024, 0666|IPC_CREAT); 
     printf("\nShared Memory Id = %d\n",shmid);

     // shmat to attach to shared memory 
     str1 = (int*) shmat(shmid,(void*)0,0);
     int *copyAdrr;
     copyAdrr = str1 ;
     while(1)
    {

     for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
         *str1=arr[i];
          printf("Data written in memory: %d\n",*str1);
          str1++;
        }
        str1 =copyAdrr;
    }
    shmdt((void*)str);
    return 0; 
    }
```